# Gradle project failed syncing

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My project was working perfectly fine on Android studio.
After updating some things by Android studio, the project stopped syncing.
I get the following message:

**"Failed to sync gradle project 'Project_Name'

Missing Android platform(s) detected: 'android-22'

Install missing platform(s) and sync project"**

The last line is supposed to be clickable so that I can install, but when I press nothing happens.

I opened the SDK Manager and everything is installed.
Tried to change the compileSdkVersion to 21, got the same error. I have it installed as well.
Tried to restart Android Studio, tried to restart the computer. Same.
Tried to delete the file where the SDK was installed and installed it again through the SDK Manager. Didn't help.

Any idea on how to solve this would be highly appreciated...

Comment: try to clean your project then build

Comment: Thanks @USKMobility, tried and the problem still occurs...

Comment: Kill the adb server and try again. On command line try "adb kill-server" clean and then rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, nothing really helped. Ended up uninstalling and installing Android Studio and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

OS: Windows 10. Project: a fork of ftc_app. I ran into this about a week ago. On opening a newly cloned repo for another user 5197programmer2 (not me), Studio failed to find target with hash string ‘android-23’. Studio offered a link to install missing platform and sync; that failed almost instantly and quietly. Studio was looking in my home directory, not that of the user who tried to open the project in Studio. Solution:

1. Studio - Tools - Android - SDK Manager – look at Android SDK location. For user 5197programmer2, this location was in my home directory c:\Users\jrasor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools. It should have been c:\Users\5197programmer2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools.
2. Edit the Android SDK location. Studio will not show 5197programmer2's AppData in the file tree.
3. **Edit the path directly in the box above the file tree**: it will act like AppData is a hidden directory.
4. Continue. Studio will claim success, but the project will still not open; it will show the same failure to find the target. But this time the link to install the missing target and sync should work. Click it.
5. Installation should proceed, and gradle finish with no complaints.